# Plotting with zero-height y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a printable inch-to-mm converter: a 1-D scale with inches on top and mm at the bottom. I've got this so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from fractions import Fraction

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax1.set_xlim(0, 25.4)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.0f}')
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))

ax2.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1/16))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: str(Fraction(x)))
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1/32))

plt.yticks([0])
plt.show()
```

The problem is that it's creating a graph with too much height, so that the inch scale appears too far away from the mm scale. How can I shrink the y-axis to zero height, so that the inch and mm markings appear on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming setting the figure size in inches is accurate:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tick
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
from fractions import Fraction
x = np.linspace(0, 25, num = 100)
fig = plt.figure(num = 1, clear = True)
fig.set_size_inches(25, 2)
for subplotsN in range(0, 2, 1):
  ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, subplotsN + 1, xticks = [], yticks = [], frameon = False)
  if subplotsN == 0:
    ax.set_xlim(0, 25.4)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
    def formattingFunction(x, xTick):
      return "{:n}".format(int(x))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tick.FuncFormatter(formattingFunction))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))
    ax.set_yticks([0])
  else:
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1/16))
    def formattingFunction(x, xTick):
      return "{:n}".format(int(x * 1000.00))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tick.FuncFormatter(formattingFunction))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1/32))
    ax.set_yticks([0])
plt.show()
```

Edit: Thank you @JohanC for helping me! A function had to be defined for the formatting along with a few other details.

Comment: For the `set_major_formatter` to work directly with functions, you need matplotlib 3.4.  (For older matplotlib versions, you need to work with a `FuncFormatter()`.)

Comment: Thank you @JohanC ! Appreciate it.